# Signature version 4 authentication failed while uploading bundle

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

I receive an error when running the following command on AWS CLI

**Command**

```
 $EC2_AMITOOL_HOME/bin/ec2-upload-bundle -b my-s3-bucket/bundle_folder/bundle_name -m /tmp/image.manifest.xml -a AKIAJKHXU4GRYW7KPDBQ -s IGaclJWIIjT7ixyb2gXPfJ8Z00U469Urt5DzGhaJ
```

**Error**

> Signature version 4 authentication failed, trying different signature
>   version ERROR: Error talking to S3: Server.NotImplemented(501): A
>   header you provided implies functionality that is not implemented

I have allowed the full permission to the user but still getting this error

I have ran this command before the above command

**Command:**

```
 $EC2_AMITOOL_HOME/bin/ec2-bundle-vol -k /tmp/ce                                                                                        rt/Cpanel.pem -c /tmp/cert/certificate.pem -u 589680520298 -r x86_64 -e /tmp/cer                                                                                        t --partition gpt
```

It ran successfully and I have successfully generated image.manifest.xml

Manual Reference: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/create-instance-store-ami.html#amazon_linux_instructions

Answer (score 0):

Please Provide Correct region of your bucket to authentication array this problem will be resolved.

Comment: you can find the region on top right corner of the AWS console.